# User Apex Error - List has no rows for assignment to SObject, I have added the exact error which am getting please go through it and help me

Tags: apex, error, user

I have wrote below apex code, but its not working.

```java
public without sharing class AP_FlowQuestionCtrl {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static QuestionInfo getQuestionRecord(
            String subscriptionId,
            String uniqueName,
            String section,
            String label,
            Integer orderNum,
            String quesType
    ) {
        QuestionInfo qi = new QuestionInfo();
        try{
            if (subscriptionId != '' && subscriptionId != null) {
                Subscription__c sub = [SELECT Id, isCloned__c FROM Subscription__c WHERE Id = :subscriptionId];
                qi.isCloned = sub.isCloned__c;
                List<Subscription_Question__c> questionsList = [SELECT Id,
                                Name,
                                Answer__c,
                                Answer_Checkbox__c,
                                Answer_Picklist__c,
                                Answer_Text__c,
                                Answer_Number__c,
                                Answer_Date__c,
                                Question__c,
                                Unique_Name__c,
                                Section__c,
                                New_Question__c,
                                onFlow__c,
                                isVisible__c,
                                Subscription__c
                        FROM Subscription_Question__c
                        WHERE Subscription__c = :subscriptionId AND
                        Unique_Name__c = :uniqueName AND
                        Section__c = :section LIMIT 1];

                if(questionsList.size()>0){
                    qi.sc = questionsList[0];
                    qi.scId = questionsList[0].Id;
                    updateQuestion(questionsList[0], label, orderNum);
                }else{
                    Subscription_Question__c sq = new Subscription_Question__c();
                    sq.Subscription__c = subscriptionId;
                    sq.Unique_Name__c = uniqueName;
                    sq.Question__c = label;
                    sq.Section__c = section;
                    sq.Order__c = orderNum;
                    sq.Type__c = quesType;
                    sq.onFlow__c = true;
                    sq.isVisible__c = false;
                    if(sub.isCloned__c)
                        sq.New_Question__c = true;
                    qi.scId = createQuestionRecord(sq);
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception ex){
            Log.error(ex);
        }
        return qi;
    }


    public static void updateQuestion(Subscription_Question__c sq, String label, Integer orderNum){
        sq.onFlow__c = true;
        sq.isVisible__c = false;
        sq.Question__c = label;
        sq.Order__c = orderNum;
        try{
            update sq;
        }catch(Exception ex){
            Log.error(ex);
        }
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static String createQuestionRecord(Subscription_Question__c sc) {
        Database.UpsertResult result = Database.upsert(sc);
        String sobjLabel = result.getId().getSObjectType().getDescribe().getLabel();
        if (!result.isSuccess()) {
            for(Database.Error err : result.getErrors()) {
                System.debug('The following error has occurred while updating '+ sobjLabel +'Records.');
                System.debug(err.getStatusCode() + ': ' + err.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return result.getId();
    }

    public class QuestionInfo{
        @AuraEnabled
        public Subscription_Question__c sc;
        @AuraEnabled
        public String scId;
        @AuraEnabled
        public Boolean isCloned;
    }
}
```

The actual error am getting is[image]

Comment: Your question could provide more information to get a better answer. The error in the title is indicating that a SOQL query is not returning any result. At a guess that would be the line:
```
Subscription__c sub = [SELECT Id, isCloned__c FROM Subscription__c WHERE Id = :subscriptionId];
```

Comment: can you verify `uniqueName`  `section` and `subscriptionId` have valid values,  before you query for `Subscription_Question__c`  in your `getQuestionRecord` method ?

Comment: yes, they have Valid values.

Answer (score 1):

The error "List has no rows for assignment to SObject" means that one of your queries is returning no results in an instance where you are trying to store those results in a single record variable.

You either need to be absolutely sure that your query will return results that match your WHERE conditions, or you should store the results of your query in an sObject list instead of a single sObject variable.

```
// No Rows for Assignment to SObject     
User u = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE FirstName = 'ThisWillDefinitelyBreak' LIMIT 1];

// No Rows, but empty list gets returned back to the List<sObject> 
List<User> users = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE FirstName = 'ThisWillDefinitelyNotBreak' LIMIT 1];

 System.debug(users.size()); // 0 Records, but no error
```